# gae-init phonebook example: css not load correct?/

Tags: python, google-app-engine

After follow the tutorial extactly http://docs.gae-init.appspot.com/tutorial/#run

this is my screen

[image]

this is the error

[image]

how to solve this problem?

Comment: @lipis: could you please help?

Comment: Show us the section of HTML that references the CSS, and your `app.yaml`

Comment: all the code are downloadable from the project. I did not change anything of original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this particular tutorial is a bit dated and you'll have to follow the new instructions in order to generate the CSS and JS files.

The always updated instructions can be found in the main [README.md](https://github.com/gae-init/gae-init#initializing-or-resetting-the-project) file. So if you are starting from scratch all you have to do is to run the following:

```
$ cd /path/to/project-name
$ npm install
$ gulp
```

For more information on what else is supported run `gulp help`.